# Adding custom dependancy wont work in ML-Engine submit training

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a `.sh` script that lunches a `submit training` job as following:

```sh
    now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    JOB_NAME="campign_retention_model__$now"
    JOB_DIR="gs://machine_learning_datasets/campaign_retention"
    REGION="us-east1"
    PYTHON_VERSION='3.5'
    RUNTIME_VERSION='1.12'

    TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH="./trainer/"
    PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH="gs://machine_learning_datasets/campaign_retention"
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
    MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE="trainer.task"

    gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
      --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
      --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
      --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
      --region $REGION \
      --runtime-version=$RUNTIME_VERSION \
      --python-version=$PYTHON_VERSION \
```

Which works great (Notice that the `.sh` is located next to the trainer dir).

Due to external infra requirements, i was forced to save the content of my project within a bucket named:

```
"gs://campign_retention_code/camp_ret"
```

And hand out a stand alone `sh`, So I've just changed it to (just changed the path of `TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH`):

```sh
    now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    JOB_NAME="campign_retention_model__$now"
    JOB_DIR="gs://machine_learning_datasets/campaign_retention"
    REGION="us-east1"
    PYTHON_VERSION='3.5'
    RUNTIME_VERSION='1.12'

    TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH="gs://campign_retention_code/camp_ret/trainer"
    PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH="gs://machine_learning_datasets/campaign_retention"
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
    MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE="trainer.task"

    gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
      --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
      --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
      --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
      --region $REGION \
      --runtime-version=$RUNTIME_VERSION \
      --python-version=$PYTHON_VERSION \
```

Now when i'm running it (I moved it to a different location on the desktop to `/Users/yehoshaphatschellekens/Desktop`, to make sure its not close to my project) i'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) Source directory [/Users/yehoshaphatschellekens/Desktop/camp_ret] is not a valid directory.
```

Looking at the docs [packaging-trainer](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer) i noticed that there are two examples, one that works like my original script, which as i said, works perfectly, and another example that uses a packaged dependancy.

Why the submit job won't recognise my dependancies on `gs`, can't i just point to `--package-path` a directory from `gs` instead of my local dir?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do requires using

```
--packages gs://path/to/packages
```

INSTEAD of --package-path

Comment: @Thanks, it now gives me access failures, but i believe that your solution solved this specific issue!